# Android: Create array of ROW_IDS from cursor - but how?

Tags: android, arrays, sqlite, cursor

I have a db collection (SQLite) and i want to create an array of the ROW_IDS. I think the following should work:

```
db.open();
String Chapter = "Something";
Cursor c = db.getSetsByChapter(Chapter);
int[] ids = {};
if (c.moveToFirst()){
    int i = 0;     
 do {
 ids[i] = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(0));
 i++;
 } while (c.moveToNext());
}


db.close();
Toast.makeText(this,"The array contains " + ids.length + " elements",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

but i keep getting:
Unable to start activity Component ... java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

I'm very new to java and android coding. I have been at this for 3 days and loosing it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to show us what line the exception is occuring.

Second, `int[] ids = {};` declares an array of ints with length 0. You then try to

```
 ids[i] = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(0));
```

put data into index 0. This isn't possible, and thus an array index out of bounds exception.

Comment: So I need to figure out how many elements are in my collection before declaring the array. Looking into how I could do that.

Comment: //---get ids from entries---
    db.open();
    String Chapter = "Something";
    Cursor c = db.getSetsByChapter(Chapter);
    int[] ids = new int [c.getCount()];
    if (c.moveToFirst()){
        int i = 0;     
     do {
     ids[i] = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(0));
     i++;
     } while (c.moveToNext());
    }


    db.close();
    Toast.makeText(this,"The array contains " + ids.length + " elements",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate the array. Use a `List<int>` and then convert the list to an integer array

Comment: You can't do this. You can'tmake a list of primitives. It has to be List<Integer>. `List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();`